# Preventing database access after application license key has expired

Tags: sql-server

I'm fairly new to this so forgive me if this is a basic question.

I have an application that uses a MS SQL database as the back-end. Like most 
applications, a user is prevented from using this application if the license key has expired. I would like to know if there is a way to also prevent users from accessing the database (via SSMS) when the key has expired?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: This is something that you can easily handle in your app code, simply do not allow the application to make the db connection, or immediately close it if the license doesn't check out. You shouldn't be allowing the users to access the database outside of your app even *if* the license is valid.

Comment: I think what the OP is asking for is a way to keep a DBA or someone with backend access to SQL Server from accessing the DB directly after the expiration. To my knowledge there is no way. The best I can think of (way outside the box) is to drop all related user DBs. But they could always restore from their last backup.

Answer (score 1):

If the person has a valid MS SQL Server username and password, they will be able to access the database.

You **could** arrange your app so that the username/password they use for the app won't allow them to accesss the SQL Server database. In any case, what's the problem if your users wish to use Crystal (or whatever) to access what is, after all, their own data?

What I mean is that surely your app provides some extra service (for which they are paying you) - after that, what they do with their data is their business.

You could warn them that any **modifications** to data may invalidate/corrupt their data with respect to your application (i.e. you won't support them for that), but personally, I would be rather annoyed to be told by a vendor that I couldn't run ad-hoc reports against my own data!

[EDIT]

What you **could** do is keep any user whose privileges allow them to modify the data "secret", but give them a username/password with SELECT privileges and that way everybody's happy - they have access to their data and you can rest easy in the knowledge that users can't mess up your app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As a correction to my original post, you are correct, they can have access to their data but we don't want them to be able to access the database. We have a client that is leaving and going to a  competitor of ours. This is a proprietary database that we don't want to fall in the hands of our competitors.

Comment: @user61315, the only real solution is a licensing agreement that prohibits sharing the database code in such a way.  What prevents clients with valid licenses from sharing your database schema or code with your competitors?